# Does Chrome 55.0.2883.91 on Android properly zoom on fixed elements?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, css-position

I am not sure but I think that Chrome for Andoird started zooming on fixed elements without those elements breaking the page/layout any more on zoom.

Please check this simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3s20hru7/) in your local dev environment running latest Chrome for Android (on a mobile device).

When I zoom the page that has this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
```

and two fixed elements at the top, the zoom is done like so.

The fixed elements are positioned absolutely and can be zoomed in without having the fixed elements stay in place and break the page/layout.

This happens regardless of if the user has overridden the zoom settings in the accessibility settings or not, even the default zoom started to play nice with fixed elements I think.

Is there a changelog somewhere please for Chrome for Android for the latest update? I cannot find it and am looking to verify if this assumption is correct.

HTML

```
<div class="fixed-placeholder">
  <div class="site-header">
        Site Header
  </div>
  <div class="menu-icon">
        Menu
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    Content
</div>
<div class="content">
    Content
</div>
<div class="content">
    Content
</div>
<div class="content">
    Content
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fixed-placeholder {
    height: 6em;
    display: block;
}
.site-header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 3em; /* same as fixed-placeholder to avoid page jump or content moving under the fixed element */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    font-size: 2rem;
    /*width: 80vw;*/
    /*display: none;*/
}
.menu-icon {
    position: fixed;
    height: 3em;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 40%;
    font-size: 2rem;
    /*width: 20vw;*/
}
.content {
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```